# Netbeans incorrectly highlighting html opening/closing tags in php script

Tags: html, netbeans, syntax, tags, highlighting

```
<form name='toggleAutoManual' action='action' onchange='this.submit()'>
<input type='hidden' name='formSubmit' value='true'>
Mode: 
<?php  

if ($autoFlag==1)
{
    ?>
<input type='radio' value='Auto' checked='checked' name='autoFlag'>Auto / <input type='radio' value='Manual' name='autoFlag'>Manual
<?php
}
else
{
 ?>
<input type='radio' value='Auto' name='autoFlag'>Auto / <input type='radio' value='Manual' checked='checked' name='autoFlag'>Manual
<?php
}
?>
</form>
```

---

the above snippet uses php to check a variable, and based on that checks either the "auto" or "manual" checkbox. My question is about how netbeans highlights the syntax. When you click an opening html tag in netbeans, it highlights it yellow, and also the closing tag yellow. A tag is highlighted in red if it cannot find a closing tag. My "form" tags get highlighted in red. This really bugs me. This error happens several times throughout my script, on a number of different tags. Am I doing something wrong here? Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tha's not how you should use your tags, rather use something like this:

```
<form name='toggleAutoManual' action='action' onchange='this.submit()'>
<input type='hidden' name='formSubmit' value='true' />
Mode: 
<?php  
if ($autoFlag==1){
echo "<input type='radio' value='Auto' checked='checked' name='autoFlag' />Auto / <input type='radio' value='Manual' name='autoFlag' />Manual";
}else{
 echo "<input type='radio' value='Auto' name='autoFlag' />Auto / <input type='radio' value='Manual' checked='checked' name='autoFlag' />Manual";
}
?>
</form>
```

This should fix your problems

Comment: Thanks for the input, but...

First off, that did not make a difference. Netbeans is still balking at me. 
Second, I thought that was a question of style or preference; when I need to output html code in a php script, each time I make a judgement call about which would be easier to read, closing the tag or using an echo. I don't think I am using tags 'incorrectly' when I do that.

Comment: Ok, can you try with new code I edited? I added the closing slash to the input elements, maybe that will help

Comment: Turns out I had an unclosed table tag much earlier in the code, that's why netbeans got mad since it didn't want a form being declared inside of a table tag outside of a td tag. Would be nice if netbeans could have referred me to that instead of just making my tag red with no explanation. Problem solved, thanks for looking at this for me. I think I need to switch to phpStorm or some other IDE.

Comment: I see, I'm glad you figure it out, I can also recomend notepad++ which is a great IDE.

Comment: I love notepad++ but its just an editor. I know it can be used as an IDE with some plugins but I need a full php solution that can connect to a repository.

Comment: gotcha, never been a fan of netbeans , may I suggest eclipse for PHP developers ?  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliosr